# Redactor: Adding target="_blank" to links

Tags: redactor

Redactor is a neat WYSIWYG JavaScript-based editor.

What is the proper way to add `target="_blank"` to all links created using the Redactor editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Redactor 1.2.5 it is now possible to simply set `pasteLinkTarget` in Redactor's settings when instantiating the editor:

https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/paste/#setting-pasteLinkTarget

This allows you to ensure that all links pasted or entered into the editor open in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "Open link in new tab" is checked when inserting a link.

[image: Redactor]

Comment: This works, but only for links inserted through the modal window. What about pasted links which get auto-converted?

Comment: I don't have experience with Redactor, but looking at their demo website, it seems that you have two options: 1 - you can click on every one of those pasted links, and once again click on the same "Link" button - this will allow you to edit the link and show that checkbox, or 2 - you can view HTML source in Redactor, copy all of it in a text editor on your PC, and then do a search & replace (add `target="_blank"` to all `<a>` elements).

Comment: I doubt most of the users will be willing to do that. I guess I should just parse and fix the links server-side.

Comment: Well I wasn't aware of your use-case, I did not know it will be your users who are using this.

Comment: for the pasted links you will need to use the `pasteAfterCallback`  check the documentations [pasteAfterCallback](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/#api-pasteAfterCallback)

Comment: @BoMilanovich even after checking this checkbox, the url doesn't appear with the `target="_blank"` is there a workaround?